# How to integrate IBM Watson Assistant services in Pure JavaScript local development Python backend

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I am going to use the IBM Watson assistant as my model to answer my questions. at the moment I created a voice recognition part using Javascript and I want to pass that identified values into IBM Watson's API using javascript.

I didn't find any related resources at the moment but if someone suggests me a way to do that it will be really helpful for me.

Flow:
User talks ----->> Convert that speech into text
Now I have the text ----->> Pass it into IBM APIs to get the response

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, a bit confused by your question. “Pure JavaScript… Python back end”

But here are the fundamentals. I recommend doing the Watson API calls from a lightweight HTTP Server (Python Flask or JavaScript Express) you create an API POST endpoint and pass in the text from your UI/client and then from within the server side code you make calls to the Watson API with your API Key, and then pass the Watson API response back up to the caller. Similar to how in the Watson examples they show curl being used; you would fetch these “curl” API calls from your running HTTP server (again JavaScript Express or Python Flask). Your running HTTP Server becomes the Watson Assistant “client application” as mentioned in the documentation.

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2

Side note, my experience has been with using the JavaScript Watson Development SDK and Express and it was a really good experience. I personally would recommend that over Python in this scenario.